# Delete sublists containing exactly two positive numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to eliminate all the sub lists containing exactly two positive numbers? My list is

```
M = {{-2,4,0,12}, {0,7}, {3,6,9,11}, {2,3,0}, {1,4}, {-3,7,8}, {-2,5}, 
 {-7,-3,0,1,2}, {1,2,3}};
```

However, going through the *Mathematica* Tutorial on [List Manipulation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingListsOverview.html) has garnered me help on how to specify my criteria. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Assuming that your `List` is only ever 3 levels deep, `DeleteCases[M, _?(2 == Count[#, _?Positive] &)]]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 9):

`Select[]` + `Count[]` is a more straightforward approach:

```
m = {{-2, 4, 0, 12}, {0, 7}, {3, 6, 9, 11}, {2, 3, 0}, {1, 4}, {-3, 7, 8},
     {-2, 5}, {-7, -3, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}};

Select[m, Count[#, _?Positive] != 2 &]
   {{0, 7}, {3, 6, 9, 11}, {-2, 5}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

But if you insist on `DeleteCases[]`:

```
DeleteCases[m, v_ /; Count[v, _?Positive] == 2]
```

Comment: Maybe is useful to note that this solution removes any sublist that contains al least two positive numbers, so this code removes elements `{{-2, 4, 0, 12}, {2, 3, 0}, {1, 4}, {-3, 7, 8}, {-7, -3, 0, 1, 2}}` from the main list (if I understood well user35305 asked to remove sublist formed by `exactly` two positive numbers, i.e. just the element {1, 4})

Comment: @Guido, OP said "exactly two", not "only two". If the latter was in fact intended, then you're right. (The OP did forget to mention the expected output, so...)

Comment: @JM thank you. In fact because of my not-so-good English, I was not sure to have understood correctly what was the question's expected output.

Answer (score 7):

If you meant to delete cases where there is **only** a pair of positive numbers:

```
DeleteCases[M, {x_ /; x > 0, y_ /; y > 0}]
```

Comment: Or `DeleteCases[M, {_?Positive, _?Positive}]`

Answer (score 2):

To select sublists with exactly two positive numbers using a point-free style:

```
m = {{-2, 4, 0, 12}, {0, 7}, {3, 6, 9, 11}, {2, 3, 0}, {1, 4}, {-3, 7,
    8}, {-2, 5}, {-7, -3, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}};

Select[EqualTo[2]@*Count[1]@*Sign][m]

Pick[m, Map[EqualTo[2]@*Count[1]@*Sign, m]]
```

{{-2, 4, 0, 12}, {2, 3, 0}, {1, 4}, {-3, 7, 8}, {-7, -3, 0, 1, 2}}

---

To delete sublists with exactly two positive numbers, use the following:

```
Select[Not@*EqualTo[2]@*Count[1]@*Sign][m]

Pick[m, Map[Not@*EqualTo[2]@*Count[1]@*Sign, m]]

Pick[m, Map[EqualTo[2]@*Count[1]@*Sign, m], False]
```

> {{0, 7}, {3, 6, 9, 11}, {-2, 5}, {1, 2, 3}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
 {{-2, 4, 0, 12}, {0, 7}, {3, 6, 9, 11}, {2, 3, 0}, {1, 4}, 
  {-3, 7, 8}, {-2, 5}, {-7, -3, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}};
```

Using `Replace` and `Nothing`

```
Replace[list, x_ /; Count[x, _?Positive] == 2 :> Nothing, {1}]
```

{{0, 7}, {3, 6, 9, 11}, {-2, 5}, {1, 2, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

Just some variants using `Pick` and `Reap`, `Sow` (have voted for other answers):

```
Pick[m, Total@# == 2 & /@ Map[Boole[# > 0] &, m, {2}], False]
bc[n_] := BooleanCountingFunction[{2}, Length[n]] @@ (# > 0 & /@ n);
Pick[m, bc /@ m, False]
Pick[m, Count[#, _?Positive] == 2 & /@ m, False]
Reap[Sow[#, bc@#] & /@ m, False, #2 &][[-1, 1]]
```

Comment: why not use UnitStep or friends in the first solution?

Comment: @Wjx very good suggestion. Feel free to edit (with attribution of course)...was just in a mood :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple modification of ubpdqn's answer, it seems that it will be slightly faster:

```
Pick[m,Total/@(1-UnitStep[-m]),Except@2]
```

I will always think of `UnitStep`, `UnitBox`, `Sign` and friends when dealing with these problems involving simple selection criteria as they'll be quite fast and easy to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

```
m = {{-2, 4, 0, 12}, {0, 7}, {3, 6, 9, 11}, {2, 3, 0}, {1, 4},
     {-3, 7, 8}, {-2, 5}, {-7, -3, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}};
```

Using `ReplaceAll` and `CountsBy`:

```
m /. v_?VectorQ /; (CountsBy[v, # > 0 &][True] == 2) :> Nothing

(*{{0, 7}, {3, 6, 9, 11}, {-2, 5}, {1, 2, 3}}*)
```

Or using `GroupBy`:

```
Catenate@KeySelect[GroupBy[m, Count[#, _?Positive] &], # != 2 &]

(*{{0, 7}, {-2, 5}, {3, 6, 9, 11}, {1, 2, 3}}*)
```

Or a slot-free variation (Thanks to @eldo!):

```
Catenate@KeySelect[FreeQ@2]@GroupBy[m, Count@_?Positive]
```

Comment: Very nice - A slot-free variation: `Catenate@KeySelect[FreeQ@2]@GroupBy[m, Count@_?Positive]`

Comment: Very nice slot-free variation, @eldo! :-)