# How to quickly join in the following way?

Tags: list-manipulation, table, subset, join

Consider the following table:

```
tab = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 3}];
subsets=Subsets[tab, {2}];
```

How to quickly reduce `subsets` to a 2D table of with each row being joined elements of each row of `subsets`?

This is my solution, however, it is ugly and potentially slow:

```
flattened = Flatten[subsets, 1];
valseven = Range[Length[flattened]/2]*2;
valsodd = Range[Length[flattened]/2]*2 - 1;
final = Join[flattened[[valseven]], flattened[[valsodd]], 2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `valseven` and `valsodd`

```
Join[flattened[[2 ;; ;; 2]], flattened[[1 ;; ;; 2]], 2] == final
```

> True

Even shorter is

```
Flatten @* Reverse /@ subsets == final
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

In addition:

```
MapThread[Join[#2, #1] &, Transpose@subsets] == final

(* True *)
```

Or:

```
MapApply[Join[#2, #1] &]@subsets == final

(* True *)
```

**Edit**

In [point-free](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/296874/106) style:

```
MapThread[ReverseApplied[Join], Transpose@subsets] == final

MapApply[ReverseApplied[Join]]@subsets == final

(* True
   True *)
```