# How to quickly join in the following way?

Tags: list-manipulation, table, subset, join

Consider the following table:

```
tab = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 3}];
subsets=Subsets[tab, {2}];
```

How to quickly reduce `subsets` to a 2D table of with each row being joined elements of each row of `subsets`?

This is my solution. However, it is ugly and potentially slow:

```
compiledJoin = 
  Compile[{{tab1, _Real, 2}, {tab2, _Real, 2}}, Join[tab1, tab2, 2], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
flattened = Flatten[subsets, 1];
valseven = Range[Length[flattened]/2]*2;
valsodd = Range[Length[flattened]/2]*2 - 1;
final = compiledJoin[flattened[[valseven]], flattened[[valsodd]]];
```

Comment: This post has somehow duplicated [300781](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/300781/142).  I am voting to close the present item as a duplicate.  Please update the earlier one as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don' t need `valseven` and `valsodd`

```
compiledJoin[flattened[[2 ;; ;; 2]], flattened[[1 ;; ;; 2]]] == final
```

> True